# How should I test my JPA layer?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am using Arquillian for integration tests and I want to test my repository layer which use JPA. I tried using DBSetup but it tells me that Destination class is not found so I wonder if there are other approaches to setting up database with test data for each test? And is it normal that you don't have autoincrement enabled on the test database so that you can insert rows with the same primary key after have removed the data from the last run test?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set up an integration schema with a subset of your PROD data.  I have done this using Oracle, where I kept a base DMP (dump of the schema for use with datapump import) file of the schema in my repository.  If the schema changes I update the DMP.  My goal was to get the tests to a point where they could be run multiple times against the same DMP.  That way I wouldn't have to get a CI tool to reimport the DMP every time the tests were to be run.

In every test revert the changes you make.  If you add an item, remove it and all of its history data.  If you modify a record, change it back.  If you do this you shouldn't need to re

At no point in your testing should you find a record using an autoincrement id.  If you do this there is a chance a future test may mutate the ids so they can't be found again.  Always find by a natural key (first_name, last_name, middle_name or SSN for example) or by some other method that will ALWAYS exist in the future.

If your PROD schema must change, change your integration schema first.  Run your tests against it and then change your PROD schema.

You should also refrain from obtaining new sessions as often as possible.  Obtaining sessions will be very costly.